# Raspberry Pi 3 kubernetes face recognition cluster

Tags: raspberry-pi, cloud-computing

I need an advice whether this system is possible the way I planned to implement it. I got a project to build a kubernetes cluster for face recognition using raspberry pi 3 devices. The idea is to have one single RP3 device with web camera and that device should send the frames to kubernetes cluster for face recognition. Only data that I need from the cluster is the number of faces, not who the person on the frame is. This process should run continuously, the camera is filming, sending frames, getting number of faces for each frame and storing that data on some cloud server(*it's not storing video, just timestamp and number of faces). Also, I want to cluster to automatically scale if there is sudden increase in need for computing power.

The implementation so far:
All RP3 devices are configured to run Ubuntu server version 22.
I have also already set up the cluster using k3s and also built a dummy face recognition  app using java with spring boot as it's web framework. The app is built into docker image and than deployed to the cluster. After that the nodeport service was created using the deployment.
The face recognition app can get an url to image and it returns number of faces recognised. Right now I access the node via it's local IP adress and than send the link of some google image with human faces and it prints number of faces on the webpage.

Question:
However, I am unsure how to continue from here. I have started making web cam app for RP3 but I am unsure how to send frames to the cluster. Also, I want to be able just to send the frame without knowing the IP address of each individual node in the cluster. Also, is it possible for cluster to automatically scale in a way if more processing power is needed, that the number of pods automatically increases or that mechanism needs to be implemented manually?

Sorry for the long question.

Comment: Why do you think this is a IoT question? Questions about Kubernetes would probably be better asked on ServerFault

Comment: @hardillb Thanks for the answer! I thought this is a good place because of raspberry pi devices. I will consider asking elsewhere.

Comment: A Raspberry Pi is a generate purpose computer, just because they can be used in an IoT context doesn't mean all use is